# Derivatives of trace of complicated function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, trace

When $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive semi-definite and hermitian symmetric matrices,
what is the derivative and second derivatives of 
$f(x) = tr(x^2 A (xB + C)^{-1})$, for $x>0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Consider $f(x) = x^2 A ( x B + C )^{-1}$. Then we have
  $$
  f(x) (x B + C) = x^2 A
  $$
  Differentiating on both sides yields
  $$
  f(x) B + \frac{df}{dx}(x) (x B + C)  = 2 x A
  $$
  So we get
  $$
  \frac{df}{dx}(x) = 2 x A (x B + C)^{-1} - x^2 A (x B + C)^{-1} B (x B + C)^{-1}
  $$
- The trace function is linear. So its derivative is itself.
- Next you combine these derivatives to get the composite function.

Answer (score 0):

Define the matrix
$$\eqalign{
M &= Ax^2(C+Bx)^{-1} \\
}$$
and calculate its differential and derivative
$$\eqalign{
M(C+Bx) &= Ax^2 \\
M(B\,dx) + dM(C+Bx) &= 2Ax\,dx \\
dM &= (2Ax-MB)\,(C+Bx)^{-1}\,dx \\
P=\frac{dM}{dx} &= (2Ax-MB)\,(C+Bx)^{-1} \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new matrix.

Then calculate its derivatives.
$$\eqalign{
f &= {\rm Tr}\big(M\big) \\
\frac{df}{dx}
 &= {\rm Tr}\big(P\big)    
 \;=\; {\rm Tr}\Big((2Ax-MB)\,(C+Bx)^{-1}\Big) \\
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big(
   \left(2A+PB\right)(C+Bx)^{-1} - (2Ax-MB)\,(C+Bx)^{-1}B(C+Bx)^{-1}
   \Big) \\
}$$